# VS 2010: How to make button disabled after deleting from the text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

In Visual Studio 2010, i want that the button will be disabled if there is nothing in the text box.
It is started as disabled and becomes enabled when i'm typing something in the text box.
But when I'm deleting everything from the text box, it is still enabled.
this is what I've done:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }       

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == null)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
if (textBox1.Text == null)
```

should be

```
if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
```

The Text property will not be null (which generally is taken to mean the absence of any value), but rather string.Empty, which represents a string of zero length.

A shorter way to write this is:

```
button1.Enabled = (textBox1.Text != string.Empty);
```

Comment: Eric, nice call.  I posted the same shorter implementation before realizing you already had.

Comment: or, button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)

Comment: @Phil: Not that it is likely to ever matter for a WinForms app, but string.IsNullOrEmpty does an extra, unnecessary check for null :-)